# Zxing barcode scanner exception when clicking on scan button in asus transformer TF101 android tablet device?

Tags: android, zxing

I am getting below exception when i launch application in asus transformer TF 101 and after clicking scan button it shows redline in the middle of the screen but no rectangle view to scan the image.Can any one tell me how to fix this issue?Thanks in advance.

> 10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): Unexpected error
>   initializating camera 10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed 10-15 17:12:53.630:
>   WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1297) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.camera.CameraConfigurationManager.setDesiredCameraParameters(CameraConfigurationManager.java:73)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.camera.CameraManager.openDriver(CameraManager.java:132)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.CaptureActivity.initCamera(CaptureActivity.java:281)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   jim.h.common.android.lib.zxing.CaptureActivity.surfaceCreated(CaptureActivity.java:181)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:533) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:81) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:169) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1617)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-15 17:12:53.630:
>   WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-15 17:12:53.630:
>   WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   10-15 17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 10-15
>   17:12:53.630: WARN/CaptureActivity(2500): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

This means there is a bug in the device, or else you have modified our code in some way to send a request or use features that the camera does not support. Undo your changes, and/or try commenting out camera config until you see what it is rejecting. Look for earlier errors from the camera driver.